# AWS Amplify Access Denied when Pushing to Cloud

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am following [this](https://amplify-ios-workshop.go-aws.com/40_add_api/10_amplify.html) tutorial for integrating AWS Amplify into iOS. I added the GraphQl API backend, but when I try to push it to the cloud, i get this error:

```
❯ amplify push
⠙ Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.(node:75854) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:831:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
(node:75854) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:75854) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
⠇ Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.
```

It then hangs and I have to Ctrl-C to get out of it.
I tried troubleshooting my AWS CLI environment by running `amplify configure` then followed the prompts to create a new user. The new user has the AdministratorAccess policy attached to its permissions, but it still has the same AccessDenied error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just experienced the same and I noticed my error was I did `amplify configure` while logged in to another account where the application did not exist in.

The solution for me was, I logged into the right account and did `amplify configure` again.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dillion mentioned, the creation of a new user (`amplify configure`) may be the right option, and sometimes the restoration of the cloud state is important `amplify pull --restore`, followed with the creation of what you were intended to do.

Answer (score -1):

Not a correct answer from anyone so I will answer a answer also.
here it is...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).